# Create dynamic filename, based on attribute value, for output of QGIS model

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler, file-path, save

### Basic  idea

Every user running a model selects a folder where the output of the model, a raster, should be stored as a file. The filename should be created automatically, based on an attribute value (timestamp) to succesively store the output of the same workflow for inputs representing different moments in time.

### Context

I created a model with QGIS 3.26 that does the following: 1) download a JSON-file from an URL, 2) load the file in QGIS as point layer, 3) run `v.surf.rst` to create an interpolated surface (raster). For `Model Output` of `v.surf.rst`, I set a name. When I now run the model, I am prompted to define manually a filepath + filename where the output should be saved to. This model runs perfectly.

### The problem

The online JSON-file is updated in regular intervals. So the model should run repeatedly and it should grab the timestamp in the attribute named `time` of the downloaded JSON file. The filename should be created based on the timestamp, avoiding to create manually a filename each time the model runs and to have consistent filenames reflecting the time they represent.

### What I tried

I added a `File/Folder` input named `save_to`, type set to `Folder`: it promts me to select a folder when I run the model (this is because the modul should run on different machines for different users).

The idea now is to use this folder path for the output. I thus set the output value to `Pre-calculated Value` and use the created variable `@save_to` using this expression: `@save_to ||  'output.tif'`. Like this, the file is saved to the path defined in the prompt when running the model under the static filename `output.tif`.

### Question / where I'm stuck

The last step is now to make this filename dynamic, based on the attribute field name `time` from the layer I downloaded. How to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around, I finally succeeded with the following syntax. The variable `@Load_layer_into_project_OUTPUT` is created automatically: it stores the layer that is loaded in step 2 of the model, the `Load layer into project` algorithm.

This varible can be used to access the field called `time` of this layer with:

1. `get_feature_by_id ()` to get one of the features of the layer
2. `attribute()` to get the value of the attribute `time`
3. `string` to convert the timestamp to a text/string
4. format the text string with regex to a proper format for a filename (not represented here to make the expression easier to read)
5. concatenate using pipes `||`: file path (stored in variable `@save_to`), the filename from above (steps 1-4) plus the file-extension `.tif`.

All together, the expression to create path to folder selected in input + dynamic filename based on attribute field `time` looks like:

```
    @save_to ||  
    to_string (
        attribute ( 
            get_feature_by_id ( 
                @Load_layer_into_project_OUTPUT, 
                1
            ),
            'time'
        )
    ) || 
    '.tif'
```

[image]

---

Edit: the **Download File** part, by the way, looks like this:

URL:

`https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.meteoschweiz.messwerte-lufttemperatur-10min/ch.meteoschweiz.messwerte-lufttemperatur-10min_de.json`

File Destination:

```
replace ( @save_to  || '\\', '\\\\', '\\' ) || 
left( regexp_replace(to_string (now()),'(-|T|:)','_'), 16)|| 
'.json'
```

[image]

The **Load Layer into project** looks like this:

Layer: select Algorithm Output and then "File destination" from algorithm "Download file"

Loaded Layer name:

`'measurement_' ||  left( regexp_replace(to_string (now()),'(-|T|:)','_'), 16)`

[image]

Comment: Here is another possible solution: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/446636/using-input-parameter-as-part-of-sql-query-in-qgis-model/448131#448131