# QGIS model: save downloaded file with filename based on one of its attribute values

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler

### Context

Using QGIS modeler (currently with QGIS 3.26.1) with the [`Download File`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/filetools.html#qgisfiledownloader) algorithm, you can use a filename based on an expression and thus are able to give the saved file a name based on e.g. the current time, using the function [`now()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#now).

### Question

The JSON-file I download this way contains an attribute named `reference_ts` with the timestamp of the measurement saved in it. I want to include this value in the filename. Is this possible?

### What I tried

What is possible is to access this attribute in later steps after the saved file is loaded to QGIS, [see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/440341/88814), because the layer loaded by a modeler algorithm can be accessed by a variable, created automatically, that gives access to the output of the algorithm. But in the `Download File`, there is not yet an output that could be accessed. So the attribute should be available directly.

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem. So I save the downloaded file in a temp folder (`/var/tmp`) because it needs to be downloaded to be used, it cant be a *memory layer*. I use an expression like this one `'/var/tmp/'||'some_text_' ||  layer_property(  @some_layer ,'name')||'_'||format_date(now(),'yyyyMMdd_HHmm')||'.csv'`. Then I use the *Load layer into project* with the *"File destination" from algorithm "Download file"` as `Using algorithm output` for the input layer. So the downloaded file should be usable in your model.

Comment: The problem is not how to include the current date/time (`now()`) in the filename - I solved that part. The question is rather how to include the value of an attribute in the filename.

Comment: OK maybe with two steps since the file can not be used before having been downloaded.

Comment: If you post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could do this with two steps since the file can not be used before having been downloaded : First download the and then load it to access the attributes.

I had the same problem. So I save the downloaded file in a temp folder (`/var/tmp`) because **it needs to be downloaded to be used**; it can't be a *memory layer*. I use an expression like this one:

```
'/var/tmp/'||'some_text_' || 
layer_property(  @some_layer ,'name')||'_'||
format_date(now(),'yyyyMMdd_HHmm')||'.csv'
```

Then I use the *Load layer into project* with the *"File destination" from algorithm "Download file"* as *Using algorithm output* for the input layer. So the downloaded file should be usable in your model.